# How to get the price of all simple products assigned to configurable products in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price, simple-product

I am trying to display prices of all the simple products which are assigned to the configurable products. For that I am using:

```
<?php 
    $attributes = $configurable->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);
    foreach($attributes as $attrId => $attribute){
        $att_value = $attribute['values'];
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($att_value); echo "</pre>";
    }
?>
```

After this is I am not getting price of the simple products, although I got the variations of the configurable product. But I want to display the price of the simple products. How can I do this?

Comment: By using Configurable Product Id. Load all simple products. In loop `getPrice` function  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740555/how-to-get-model-and-product-collection-in-magento-2

Comment: @AnkitShah Can you please help me to do that..? I tried alot, But not working... 
`<?php 
    $productCollection =    $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
   
$collection =     $productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load(    $configurable_pro_id);
 ?>` 
But Again its showing all the simple products.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code to get data of simple products assigned to configurable products.

```
    $configurableOptions = $_product->getConfigurableAttributesData();

    foreach ($configurableOptions['matrix'] as $option) {
       echo $option['price'];
    }
```

You can observe the reference file for more details.

```
\vendor\magento\magento2-base\dev\tests\functional\tests\app\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Test\Constraint\AssertConfigurableProductPage.php
```

Comment: This is working. Thanks...But I am getting all the simple products instead current category's configurable products->simple products...How to get these by category?

Comment: As per the question, you need to use/send configurable product into $_product to get the sample products price, those are assigned to configurable product. As i mention please have a look at reference file to get more detailed information.