# How to get the price of all simple products assigned to configurable products in magento 2 listpage?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I referred the link :
[stackexchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142485/how-to-get-the-price-of-all-simple-products-assigned-to-configurable-products-in) but I am not getting any results.
I have used following code in Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

```
$configurableOptions = $_product->getConfigurableAttributesData();

    foreach ($configurableOptions['matrix'] as $option) {
       echo $option['price'];
    }
```

**I got an error like :
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$_children = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);
                    foreach ($_children as $child){
                        echo $child->getPrice();
                    }
```